# android sqlite delete from list menu

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey guys I have a list menu that's created from a strings column of a database . When a user clicks on a list menu item, they will delete it. I'm doing this by passing the list item position to the delete function on my DBAdapter.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  db.deleteContact(position);
  }
```

The function finds the corresponding row index and deletes it.

```
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) {
  return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
  }
```

The problem (which is probably very obvious to most of you) is that when a user deletes, lets say list menu item 2, and the corresponding index is deleted from the table, the list menu refreshes and the item previously in position 3 is now in position 2. if the user tries to delete that, the delete function receives "2" as a parameter but the index of the desired row to be deleted is 3.

I know this is a silly problem, but can someone suggest an effective workaround? thanks

Comment: i don't understand what the issue is. what would you rather happen? that your item is deleted off your database but not the listview? Also, why would you pass `int position` into your method when your delete method deletes based on `long id`, also supplied.

Comment: If I have 5 rows, and I click the middle one to delete it it works just fine. However, the list refreshes so that the range is always between 1-5, 1-4, 1-3 as items are deleted. Thats fine too. But the Index of the rows remains the same, i.e if I delete row 3, I'll be left with 1,2,4,5 but the user still submits a request for row 3 to be deleted of he clicks the 3rd item in the refreshed list. So nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't delete by position. The `id` provided in the `onListClickItem` method is here to help you. Replace your code above by:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  db.deleteContact(id);
  }
```

provided that your `KEY_NAME` is the primary key of your table. If not, replace `KEY_NAME` by the name of the primary key field.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I'll try that. Thanks

edit: Worked, thanks so much for your help

Comment: Note: this will work as expected if you follow the standard android documentation on how to populate the list using a ListAdapter and a valid Cursor.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the list is populated with a ListAdapter and it seems to have a similar problem after testing. Maybe I should pass something else to the delete function. Thanks for your input all the same.